# In AdminLTE3: How to hide PushMenu side bar not only under 992px width?

Tags: bootstrap-4, adminlte

using AdminLTE 3.0.4, and would like to hide (not only collapse) the PushMenu side bar whenever the screen resolution is under 1366px width.

Under 992px, it auto-hides it, but I'm not clear if this is done by Bootstrap or by the AdminLTE css or js, and what is the simplest way to configure it to auto-hide the menu, as if it was a mobile, under 1366px (instead of 992px).

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">

        <div class="brand-link">...</div>

        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
                <div class="image"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-user"></i></div>
                <div class="info">...</div>
            </div>

            <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
            <nav class="mt-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                <li></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
     </aside>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your sidebar is managed by `sidebar-mini` class, so please find `JS` that toggle `sidebar-mini` on `992px` breakpoint and change that into `1366px` breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, I can't find that. 

Firstly, as you can see in the HTML code, the class ```sidebar-mini``` is not explicitly mentioned. 

Secondly, within adminlte.js, while there is the PushMenu function, it includes an "autoCollapseSize" default set to 992, but that refers only to the Collapse (and can be set by a parameter, so it's not a problem) - it doesn't refer to Hide/Close. I don't find that mobile breakpoint also in the AdminLTE CSS. Is it possible that it's handled by Bootstrap? And if so, how do I change that setting?

Comment: you can't do with bootstrap, I set a breakpoint at https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/index.html and I found that If I add `sidebar-mini` class in body tag, its shows sidebar and if I remove it, its collapse

Comment: The thing is, I'm not looking to Collpase it, but to Close it, like in mobile (under 992px). I've now looked at the <body> tag. There's no difference in its classes between a Collpase view, on 1000px, and a Hide view on 992px and below. In both cases it remains: ```class="sidebar-mini layout-fixed sidebar-closed sidebar-collapse"```. I can't find it...

Comment: in 992px sidebar also visible when you click on hamburger menu, in 992px, its just remove width of sidebar and when you upto 992px, its give width to sidebar

Comment: I cant show you but its working 100% in my browser, now you need to find it in your JS

Comment: Yes, it should still show the Sidebar when the hamburger button is clicked, but auto-hide (not just collpase) it otherwise, as it does under 992px. You say that on a breakpoint of 992px what happens is that the AdminLTE JS sets the width of the class ```sidebar``` to 0 - but I just don't find it. How can I trace that please?

Comment: you can set debugger on it so, you can trace all next steps of it

Comment: yes autohide is done by JS in adminLTE, and you can achieve it with add  `sidebar-mini` class when user resize to 1366px or below

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work... Even in the demo link you've mentioned, Body tag already has the class ```sidebar-mini``` - it's not what's controlling Hide directly.

Comment: I've tried to debug it with Chrome DevTools, and I just don't manage to find it...

Comment: Can you help me locate the specific explicit call which Hides the PushMenu? @nisharg-shah

Comment: adminlte.js 623 line, you can see that autoCollapseSize is set to 992, you can change it to 1366, so sidebar collapse at 1366px. here is the proof https://imgur.com/FJeqFG9

Comment: Thank you, but again - the "autoCollapseSize" is not the problem. It can be set as a parameter of the PushMenu. But it defines only the Collpase (to a narrow column), not the Hide, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

For hiding:

```
 $('[data-widget="pushmenu"]').PushMenu("collapse");
```

For opening:

```
 $('[data-widget="pushmenu"]').PushMenu("expand");
```

And toggling:

```
 $('[data-widget="pushmenu"]').PushMenu("toggle");
```

Your question's answer:

```
if (screen.width < 1366)
        $('[data-widget="pushmenu"]').PushMenu("collapse");
```